# Formual checking two cells with Search

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out a formula that will check two things in two cells that has SEARCH in it.  I have made this and does not work.  I changed AND to OR and it is working and giving me a response of 1 (i.e. I ensured the data in the other workbooks has the data to test this.  What am I missing?

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"attach*","restart","shut down","shutdown","reboot","out of rotation","power off","ripple start","kill","break mirror","stop* service","service stop*"},'RFC Data'!AP4)),'RFC Data'!L4="No"),1,"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the search in sumproduct and test if the return is greater than 0:

```
=IF(AND(SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"attach*","restart","shut down","shutdown","reboot","out of rotation","power off","ripple start","kill","break mirror","stop* service","service stop*"},'RFC Data'!AP4))))>0,'RFC Data'!L4="No"),1,"")
```

Comment: I will give that a try and let you know... tyvm!

Comment: Works like a champ!  A big TYVM!

Comment: @Ducatiduke please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.